# RabbitMQ always connect to guest user remotely

Tags: java, windows, configuration, rabbitmq

If I try to connect remotely using new `admin(test)` it will connect, but if the same program is ran through a remote machine it will connect to `guest`.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("192.168.1.6");
            factory.setUsername("test");
            factory.setPassword("test");
           //factory.setPort(5267);
            Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```

[image]
and I am to fetch messages from my queue. My variables are set.

[image]

My conf file is

```
  [
    {rabbit,[{loopback_users,[]}]}
  ].
```

If I run the same program on a remote machine it will show connect as guest:
[image]

What is my mistake? because connecting remotely I am not able to fetch message form queue as guest user

My amqp listening port is below. Do I need to change anything here?
Listening ports

```
Protocol    Bound to    Port
amqp    0.0.0.0 5672
amqp    ::  5672
```

Comment: I did not work with RabbitMQ before, so just a thought. What if you disable `guest` accounts? What if it will be necessary to login as a `regular` user, and all guests are blocked.

Comment: ok so I tried this approach also, I deleted the 'guest' user and then tried login using 'test' (test user is still their). It showed 'Authentication Failure'

Comment: Is there a standard client for RabbitMQ? If so, it is possible to login using this standard client now ?

Comment: Ok will try some different approach and will let you know, Thanks @RafaelOsipov

Answer (score 2):

Your client library(probably RabbitMQ provided client?) is using guest/guest as default username and password. Check com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory's source code, especially DEFAULT_USER and DEFAULT_PASSWORD. You might need to change it to use new id and password if you don't want to use guest/guest.

Comment: Excatly this is what i did. Since guest user has not previlage to be accessed remotely I created a new admin id and did it